# Using AJAX to submit forms

Tags: javascript, ajax

This is an AJAX problem

I have written a program to grade a quiz. I want to write a generic program which checks how many answers there are sends the answers, the questions, and the name of the `mySql` database that I want to check the answers against. It seems at first that I don't even need AJAX but I don't know another way to send more variables than what there are in the inputs of the form. I would think the average Joe using my site wouldn't know which database to compare the answers to.

When I had a submit button I got that the `xmlhttp.readystate==4` and that `xmlhttp.status==0`. I then changed the submit button to a regular button and called the function using `onClick` instead of `onSubmit` but now I get `xmlhttp.readystate==2` and `xmlhttp.status==200`. I of course want `xmlhttp.readystate==4` and `xmlhttp.status==200`. I have placed the html form and javascript code below. I appreciate any help.

The submit button was created using `<input type="submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="openServcon()">`

The regular button was created using `<button type="button" onClick="openServcon()">Submit</button>`

The website is not letting me show the code but it is located at http://www.saopaulopremiumenglish.com/tests/test5

Comment: I think you'd better add the relevant code right here (don't forget to use the code block from the bar to format it. I've done it for you for the code you've already put

Comment: Exra, as a novice you may want to check out something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) , especially for Ajax methods.  The jQuery library will handle a lot of little things like HTTP status codes and button click-handling for you.